# react native : There is way to do an haburger icon to open/close the sidebar menu and avatar for drawer?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

there is way to do an hamburger icon to open/close the sidebar menu ?
i try to do an icon that will open or close the side bar but i couldn't find how with react nav 5 .
also i need to know how to put an avatar png into the drawer menu

```
import Settings from '../screens/Settings';
import Screen1 from '../screens/Screen1';
import Screen2 from '../screens/Screen2';
import Screen3 from '../screens/Screen3';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const MaterialTopTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const MaterialBottomTabs = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
const BottomTabs = createBottomTabNavigator();

const HomeStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen3" component={Screen3} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItem
        label="Settings"
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}
        // activeTintColor="red"
        // inactiveTintColor="black"
        focused="true"
      />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

const AppNavigator = (props) => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
export default AppNavigator;
```

Comment: You cant mix navigators like that, you will have to nest a navigator inside another

Comment: can u show me please how to do it in my code ?

Comment: So you want a stack inside a drawer or something different ?

Comment: i want drawer and i want also stack.. i dont know if i need the stack inside my drawer . i just need them both.

Comment: Please try my answer

Comment: How did you get the hamburger icon in the navigation drawer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change your code like below.

```
   import Settings from '../screens/Settings';
import Screen1 from '../screens/Screen1';
import Screen2 from '../screens/Screen2';
import Screen3 from '../screens/Screen3';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const MaterialTopTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const MaterialBottomTabs = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
const BottomTabs = createBottomTabNavigator();

const HomeStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen3" component={Screen3} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItem
        label="Settings"
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}
      />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

const AppNavigator = (props) => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
export default AppNavigator;
```

This will nest the stack navigator inside the drawer navigator.

Comment: i want to see in my first page the "page2"  and in the drawer i want to see only "Settings" .

Comment: I updated the code to have a home stack and a settings screen in drawer, please check

Comment: i edit my code above... i want to see in my first the screen1 ..in the drawer i want to see only the settings

Comment: We'll thats a problem because you cant hide a screen from the drawer list :(, there are questions in stack without answers to that, The above code will have a home and settings screen and the drawer from left

Comment: so u say that all the screen in my app must be under the drawer ??

Comment: If you want the drawer on top, thats the way to go, to have the drawer as the root

Comment: and if i dont want the drawer as a root ? how i do ?

Comment: So you want the drawer only inside the setting screen ?

Comment: i just want screen1,screen2 ,screen3 as a stack and i want only the settings inside the drawr thats all. and screen1 will appear first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216213/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-shira).

Comment: how do i change my active tint color of the "settings" that inside my drawer ?

Comment: DrawerItem has a prop for activeTintColor you can set that

Comment: i did already but it doesnt works..i change my code above so u can try to help me

Comment: i approved your edit, but activeTintColor should be the way

Comment: try this   <DrawerItem
        label="Settings"
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}
        activeTintColor="red"
        focused="true"
      />

Comment: i need to add humburger icon to open the side bar also , how do i do it ?